# hashCode(): return of an integer after string

Tags: java, hashcode

I don't understand in this code the `hashcode()` methode: how can you return an integer if there is a string... Basically you add a string next to a number but that doesn't maje it a string
also i don't understand the function equals, what is a object o and what is a `o insteadof`

```
  public Imatriculation(int numeros, String word) {
       this.numeros = numeros; 
       this.word = word;

   }   
   public int hashCode() { 
       return this.word.hashCode() + this.numeros; 
   }

   public boolean equals(Object o) { 
       return   o instanceof Imatriculation 
             && this.word.equals(((Imatriculation) o).word) 
             && this.numeros == ((Imatriculation) o).numeros;
   }
```

Comment: `Object#hashCode()` returns `int`

Comment: And instanceOf returns true if the object passed in is an instance of the Imatriculation class.

Comment: yes i know but how for exemple SSJ87587 can be an int?

Comment: but word in `this.word.hashCode()` is a string no? we "put together" an int and a string and we just say it is an int?

Comment: `word` is a `String` class, but you are not concatenating with the string, you are adding with the return of value of the `hashCode()` method in the `String` class instance, which, is an `int`.  So it is an addition.

Answer (score 0):

As was already pointed out hashcode returns an int not a string.

"o" is simply any object in java, it could be anything, so instanceof is used to check if object "o" is an Imatriculation before going on and checking the details of the object.

Answer (score 0):

`String#hashCode()` is overriden from `Object#hashCode()` thus it also returns `int`. From the `String` source:

```
public int hashCode() {  // <- it returns int!!!
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

The main purpose of `hashCode()` is "numerically represent" instance of a class in order to determine, which bucket of [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) it should occupy.

Comment: i'm sorry but this is confusing me even more, what shoud i deduce from this?

Comment: i'm sorry but I have no idea what does confuse you. `hashCode()` returns int for every object, be it `Double`, `Integer`, `String` or `SynchronousQueue`. Why this is made so? To allow different objects to be stored in hash-table based collections. They use hash code values to distribute objects in hash table.

Comment: but in the code that i posted, there is only a line that define `hashCode()` and it is ` return this.word.hashCode() + this.numeros;` we don't use anu other methode but this one. and i fail to understand how  `  this.word.hashCode()` would convert the string into an int. it s not like there is just one hashCode() function or is it? Because I thought that anyone can make there own hashCode function and depending on if it s good or bad there are collisons. but here we somehow use letters and numbers put together and it is supposed to be an integer... How is FFYITF8658 and integer?

Comment: If you look at the code I provided, you understand how. Chars of `String` are iterated one-by-one, producing cumulative hash value. `char` in Java can be treated as `int`, so `String#hashCode()` performs operations on these `int`s, generating `int` result.

Comment: so in my hashCode() we also use your hashCode ()?

Comment: of course. (btw, it is not mine, it is from Java SE sources). To calculate hash code of composite object, we use hash codes of its fields.

Comment: but isn't it weird that they both have the same name?

Comment: Quite the opposite, this is very useful. When you have many objects of different classes, you don't need to know, how hash code function is implemented in each of them neither what is name of this function--you just call `hashCode()` on all objects and process results.